Ratio of Noncentral Chi Squared
Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables of noncentral chi squared distributions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution)$\chi_a^2(\delta)$ and $\chi_b^2(\eta)$ respectively. If $\eta = 0$, then $Z=\frac{b X}{a Y}$ is known to have noncentral F-distribution $F_{a,b}(\delta)$. In particular, when $\delta = 0$ also, it will be the central F-distribution $F_{a,b}$.
Questions :

If $\eta > 0$ and $\delta = 0$, then $\frac{a Y}{b X} = \frac{1}{Z}$ has noncentral F-distribution $F_{b,a}(\eta)$. A transformation on this density will yield the density of $Z$ in this case. Does this density have a name?
If $\eta > 0$ and $\delta > 0$, what is the most convenient way to describe the distribution of $Z$ (in terms of other known distributions) ? If there is no convenient way, what would be a closed form expression of its density?


You can't say $Z = \frac{bX}{aY}$ and $\frac{aY}{bX} = \frac{1}{Z}$ because the two cases don't have the same noncentrality parameters.  In the first case, $Y$ is central ($\eta = 0$).  In the second case, $X$ is central ($\delta = 0$).  So the only time when $Z = \frac{bX}{aY}$ and $\frac{1}{Z'} = \frac{aY}{bX}$ satisfy $Z = Z'$ is when $\delta = \eta = 0$; i.e., $Z$ is central $F$-distributed.
It seems you are interested in the case where the denominator variable is noncentral.  If the numerator is central, then this corresponds to $W = 1/Z$ where $Z$ is noncentral $F$-distributed.  I would then say that $W = 1/Z$ is inverse noncentral $F$-distributed, and we would express the PDF as
$$f_W(w) = \frac{1}{w^2} f_Z(1/w).$$
In the case where both the numerator and denominator are noncentral, I am not aware of a name of such a distribution or an expression for the density.  I imagine it would be very difficult to calculate.
